# Let $f \in \mathbb Q[x]$ be a nonconstant polynomial. Is $\mathbb Q[x]$ a finitely generated $\mathbb Q[f]$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I'm trying to understand what this Lemma is saying in the case $r=1$: (from Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*)

> [image]

If $r=1$, it seems to me to be saying that $T$ is a finitely generated module over $k[f]$.

Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because $T$ is a $k[f]$-algebra generated by the single element $x_1$, which is integral over $k[f]$: specifically, if $f=a_0+\cdots+a_dx_1^d$, then $x_1$ is a root of $$X^d+\frac{a_{d-1}}{a_d}X^{d-1}+\cdots+ \frac{a_0-f}{a_d}$$

which is a monic polynomial of $(k[f])[X]$.

Comment: I see how $k[x]$ is a $k[f]$-algebra since we have a ring homomorphism $k[f] \to k[x]$ given by inclusion. But, how is $k[x]$ a finitely generated $k[f]$-algebra?

Comment: It's a finitely generated $k[f]$-algebra because it is generated by $x$. It is a finitely generated $k[f]$-module because it's generated as a $k[f]$-algebra by an integral element.

Comment: We see that $k[x]$ is generated by $x$ over $k$, but how about over $k[f]$?

Comment: Ahh, $k$ is contained in $k[f]$, so $k[x]$ is still generated by $x$ over $k[f]$? Is this correct?

Comment: I think there is an error in your polynomial in $X$. Should that be $$X^d+\frac{a_{d-1}}{a_d}X^{d-1}+\cdots+ \frac{a_0}{a_d}-\frac{1}{a_d}f?$$

Comment: @user46372819 There was, thank you.

Comment: Just to double check, we can also say that $k[x]$ is a finitely-generated $k[f]$-aglebra since we have $k[f]$-algebra surjection $k[f][y] \to k[x]$ given by $y \mapsto x$?

Comment: @user46372819 Yes, it can be done like that. Or, if you are already seeing $k[x]$ as a $k[f]$-algebra by having $k[f]$ be a subring of $k[x]$, you could say that the smallest subring containing $k[f]$ and $x$ is $k[x]$.

Comment: Since $x$ is integral over $k[f]$ and satisfies a polynomial of degree $d$, do we have that $k[x]$ is a free $k[f]$-module of rank $d$?